# NUnit - trying to create a common test but got The test case source could not be found

Tags: c#, testing, nunit

I've decided to make my tests for a feature common, so I could pass on to it different implementations of classes but keep tests equal.

Here's the common test class:

```
internal abstract class PictureHandlingTestsBase : IlgTestBase
{
    protected PictureHandlingTestsBase(GallerySettingsBase defaultGalSettings, GallerySettingsBase altGalSettings)
    {
        DefaultGallerySettings = defaultGalSettings;
        AltGallerySettings = altGalSettings;

        // ...
    }

    [TestCaseSource(nameof(AllGallerySettings))]
    public async Task ChangeFriendlyUrlForGalleryWithPics(GallerySettingsBase gallerySettings)
    {
      // ...
    }

    // ...

    protected static object[]? AllGallerySettings { get; private set; }

    protected static GallerySettingsBase? AltGallerySettings { get; private set; }

    protected static GallerySettingsBase? DefaultGallerySettings { get; private set; }

}
```

And then I have an implementation of these tests for file system:

```
internal class FilesystemPictureHandlingTests : PictureHandlingTestsBase
{
    public FilesystemPictureHandlingTests() : base(
        new FilesystemGallerySettings(...), new FilesystemGallerySettings(...)) { }

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
      // ...
    }
}
```

And for Azure blob storage:

```
internal class AzurePictureHandlingTests : PictureHandlingTestsBase
{
    public AzurePictureHandlingTests() : base(
        new AzureGallerySettings(...), new AzureGallerySettings(...)) { }

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
      // ...
    }
}
```

But when I run tests I get:

> System.Exception : The test case source could not be found.

What does it actually mean?

Comment: Setting a static property from a constructor is fragile at best (no constructor may have been run => property is null, or multiple constructors run competing for the one and only static property).

Comment: @KlausGütter yep, I know. But `TestCaseSource()` expects only static properties. If you have any idea how to avoid this, please let me know.

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59416839/nunit-testcasesource-in-base-class-with-data-from-derived-class

Comment: @stuartd not really, I want all the tests be the same, but implementations should be different. I don't want to have derived tests at all. Basically, I already have them. It's just I can't use `TestCaseSource()`

Comment: What about having a common implementation in the base class (not marked as `[Test]`) or a helper class. In the actual test classes you then have the `[TestCaseSource]` and just delegate to the common implementation?

Comment: Yes, I have some ideas about that. I'll try it today. But I thought the implementation like that would be the best. Well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I don't have a better solution, here's what I do for now:

```
internal abstract class PictureHandlingTestsBase : IlgTestBase
{
    protected PictureHandlingTestsBase(GallerySettingsBase defaultGalSettings, GallerySettingsBase altGalSettings)
    {
        defaultGalSettings.Should().NotBeNull();
        altGalSettings.Should().NotBeNull();

        DefaultGallerySettings = defaultGalSettings;
        AltGallerySettings = altGalSettings;
    }

    [Test]
    public async Task ChangeFriendlyUrlForGalleryWithPics()
    {
        await ActualTest(DefaultGallerySettings!);

        SetUp(); // running it manually before simulating another run

        await ActualTest(AltGallerySettings!);
        return;

        async Task ActualTest(GallerySettingsBase gallerySettings)
        {
          // ... the test logic
        }
    }

    // This must exist here as I have to run it manually
    public abstract void SetUp();
}
```

First, I had to create my own abstract `SetUp()` method because I have to run it manually before changing from default settings to alternative settings. And then here's my derived class:

```
internal class FilesystemPictureHandlingTests : PictureHandlingTestsBase
{
    public FilesystemPictureHandlingTests() : base(new FilesystemGallerySettings(...), new FilesystemGallerySettings(...)) { }

    [SetUp]
    public override void SetUp()
    {
      // ...
    }
}
```